Finding overlapping polygons in the same shapefile using GeoPandas
I want to find overlapping polygons in the same shapefile. I am using parcel data.
I am using
intersection_gdf = gpd.sjoin(parcels_gdf, parcels_gdf, how='inner', predicate='intersects')

but the output for this shows polygons that share a boundary as well. I want to calculate the area of intersection and determine if the polygon has a high (>50% of the polygon) overlap. If it does I'll consider it a duplicate and remove it.
I tried using overlay methods but it didn't help. I also tried an approach where I do a join with the predicate as intersect and then touches and tried removing one from the other but I ended up with an empty DataFrame. When visualizing on ArcGIS Pro I have seen overlapping parcels.
Edit in response to the solution posted by @user2856:
The solution given is yielding an issue

The orange is the original polygon file and the purple is the output. per the logic, polygon 2 has a 50% overlap with polygon 1 and should be removed. But polygon 1 is the one that is removed from the final output.
Screenshot of the data

The source is TXGIO
Updated code with geom_id as the unique key and incorporating @user2856 code
gdf_shp = gdf_shp.explode() #the dataset has multiploygons 
    gdf_shp["orig_area"] = gdf_shp.area
   
    gdf_shp['geom_id'] = gdf_shp.groupby(gdf_shp.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.wkt)).ngroup() + 1
    gdf_shp.to_file("geom_id.shp")
   


    gdf_shp['sort_key'] = gdf_shp.apply(lambda row: 1 if pd.notna(row['STAT_LAND_']) or pd.notna(row['LOC_LAND_U']) else 0, axis=1)
    gdf_shp = gdf_shp.sort_values(by=['geom_id', 'sort_key'])
  


    gdf_shp.drop_duplicates(subset="geom_id", keep="last", inplace=True)


    gdf = gpd.overlay(gdf_shp, gdf_shp, how="intersection",keep_geom_type=False)
  

    # filter out self-intersection
    gdf = gdf[(gdf["geom_id_1"]!=gdf["geom_id_2"])]

    # Calculate proportion of poly 1 that overlaps poly 2
    gdf["overlap_area"] = gdf.area
    gdf["overlap_proportion"] = (gdf["overlap_area"] / gdf["orig_area_1"])

    # Select results > 50%
    gdf = gdf[gdf["overlap_proportion"] > 0.5][["geom_id_1", "geom_id_2", "overlap_proportion"]]



    #df[df['Pid'] == 'p01']
    # Definitely delete, they only appear in 1st ID col, i.e they're a
    # smaller poly in a big one so only one is overlapped by more than 50%
    delete = gdf[~gdf["geom_id_1"].isin(gdf["geom_id_2"])]["geom_id_1"].to_list()

    # Only delete subsequent occurrences, i.e both overlapped by more than 50%
    maybe_delete = gdf[gdf["geom_id_1"].isin(gdf["geom_id_2"])].sort_values(by="geom_id_1", ignore_index=True)
    keep = []

    for id1, id2 in maybe_delete[["geom_id_1", "geom_id_2"]].itertuples(index=False):
        # have we seen any of these before
        if not id1 in keep + delete and not id2 in keep + delete:
            keep.append(id1)
            delete.append(id2)
        elif id1 in keep:  # Seen first so delete subsequent
            delete.append(id2)
        # anything else we ignore

    # Drop any features in the delete list and write out
    gdf_new = gdf_shp[~gdf_shp["geom_id"].isin(delete)]


Like this?:
import geopandas as gpd
f = r"C:\gistest\overlaps241128.shp"
df = gpd.read_file(f)

#Plot
ax = df.plot(color="red", alpha=0.4, figsize=(10,10))
labels = [(i, pnt.x, pnt.y) for i, pnt in zip(df["id"], df.geometry.representative_point())]
for label, x, y in labels:
    ax.annotate(text=label, xy=(x,y), fontsize=24)


#Union the df with itself
df["original_area"] = df.area #Calculate the area prior to union
u = gpd.overlay(df1=df, df2=df, how="union", keep_geom_type=True, make_valid=True)
u = u.loc[u.id_1!=u.id_2] #Drop the self unions, for example polygon 1 and polygon 1
u["union_area"] = u.area #Calculate the area after the union, the area of the intersections
u["overlap_ratio"] = u["union_area"] / u["original_area_1"] #Calculate the overlap ratio

# print(u[[x for x in u.columns if "geom" not in x]])
#   id_1    original_area_1 id_2    original_area_2 union_area  overlap_ratio
#   1   938333.0475747393   2   198953.47550142417  106194.09165464353  0.11317313391989964
#   1   938333.0475747393   3   272245.3687344952   14889.421392378712  0.015867949477920047
#   2   198953.47550142417  1   938333.0475747393   106194.09165464353  0.5337634408597369
#   3   272245.3687344952   1   938333.0475747393   14889.421392378712  0.05469118340411323

#So polygon 1 is overlapped by polygon 2 by 11.3 %
#Only polygon 2 is overlapped by more than 50 %, so it should be dropped

to_drop = u.loc[u["overlap_ratio"]>0.5]["id_1"]
df2 = df.loc[~df.id.isin(to_drop)]
df2.plot(color="blue", alpha=0.4)


